# Test/Simulate SNMP traps on disk failures

Tags: test, trap, snmp

On my monitored system I configure SNMP to sent traps in the event that hardware failures occur. For example, I add the following (rather well-known) line to my `snmpd.conf` file:

```
monitor -60 -o dskPath -o DiskErrMsg "dskTable" diskErrorFlag!=0
```

(this line basically instructs SNMP to send a trap whenever the `diskErrorFlag` is set to 1 - meaning there are errors)

I need to see how these SNMP traps will actually look like, if there are disk failures (meaning that `diskErrorFlag` really gets the value 1).

I can only think of the following options:

1. Actually simulate a disk failure so that SNMP does its job and generates the trap -> I find this difficult to achieve and may be impossible to simulate for other hardware failures that I need to monitor as well...
2. Tell somehow SNMP on the monitored system to behave as if there were such a disk error (somehow similar to pushing the red test button on a smoke detector without having actual smoke...)
3. Construct the trap myself manually using the `snmptrap` command, but this does not guarantee that whatever I'm constructing looks identical to what SNMP itself will send when the event occurs.

For me, the most preferable way to test this is to use option 2 and I need your help because I don't know how to do it (if possible). Nevertheless, if there are smarter ways to do this test please let me know.

Comment: There's an answer [here](http://serverfault.com/a/498931/294707) on creating disc errors using the device mapper, `dmsetup`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But what about other hardware failures (the HDD was just an example)? I guess that the option #2 above would save the hazzle of writing a different solution for each type of hardware failure simulation... In the end the purpose is just to see how the traps composed by SNMP would look like as if the failure occurred.

Comment: Remove the negation in  `diskErrorFlag!=0` and restart snmpd. Snmptrapd will send a trap, since there are no errors and then you can change it back, once you have an idea of what you're looking at.